# How to use a image as a background with out it being blurry

Tags: html, css, image, background

The last hour of my life I have been searching all over trying to find out how to make the background of my website a image. I could not find one post that helped explain it or worked.

Code:

```
body {
   background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSdA1670FJVHsBy1-mv6eF8xnLJi5rp-09t0102mSD6QDcxObMKnA');
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

The image is extremely blurry how do I fix that?

Comment: The image you are using is only 20px wide, it will be blurry when stretched.  You will need a larger image to cover a bigger area if you are set on having a background image

Comment: What is the size I need?

Answer (score 0):

### Just use a better quality image

```css
body {
  background: url('http://images.summitpost.org/original/462463.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<h1>Some content</h1>
```

Comment: @CyrusMusic101 Just search for large images on google (see: https://ito-engineering.screenstepslive.com/s/ito_fase/m/51325/l/325495-how-to-search-google-images-for-large-images)